# serialized numbers in text files with for loop and sed

Tags: bash, for-loop, sed, text-files

I want to put serialized numbers on defined positions in a text file.
My idea is to use character patterns in the file, count up a variable and put them by using sed in the file. I tried this:

```
for number in 1 2 3 4 ; do
  sed -ibak "s/var/$number" file.txt > file2.txt
done
```

(the arguments 1 2 3 ... are not the best solution, but I think, it should work)

With this code and tiny variations of it, I get different results, but no success. 
I can cut/paste the pattern in the text, but it is always the last argument inserted (="3"). Why doesn´t sed take the iterated variable? (which is counted up, I tested it with echo).

Comment: it would be better if you provide sample input file and expected output after text processing... consider using awk/perl since sed is not suited to handle arithmetic operations

Comment: Missing closing `/` in the sed expression.

Comment: `sed -i` does not produce any output in normal circumstances. Did you add `-i` accidentally?

Comment: @anishsane No, i added -ibak because I want sed surely to replace the pattern and backup the file

Comment: Then you should have also dropped the redirection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first iteration replaces `var` by `1`, the next iteration replaces exactly the same `var` by `2`, etc. - because you operate on the same input every time, and the pattern isn't dynamic.

It's not clear what you want to achieve, so it's hard to provide a working solution.

It might be easier to reach for Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/picvar/"pic" . ++$i/e'
```

Comment: Ok, here is, what I want do to:
Code in file: "<img source="../pics/picvar.png ...>" etc. (several patterns "picvar" all over the html-file).
I´d like to put the image number automatically in the file, just by counting up like pic1, pic2, ...

Comment: The result should be: "<img source="..pics/pic1.png ..." and so on.

Comment: What you described is exactly my understanding of my snippet. The for-loop iterates "var" every round with the given argument (= a list of numbers). With sed I tried to put this in my file. But obviously something is wrong, but I don´t understand, what.

Comment: @Pjoern: Oh, the file is XML or HTML? Then don't use `sed` at all.

Comment: Yes, its html, but it could be changed in txt (without effort).

Comment: If you replace `var` by `1`, save, then replace the very same `var` by `2`, and save again overwriting the previous output, it's probably not what you want, but that's what you do.

Comment: My idea was to put "var" in my file/text before replacing it by the next number. This was, what I thought to do with sed in the loop - but with no success.

Comment: can also use `perl -pe 's/pic\Kvar/++$i/e'` or `perl -pe 's/pic\Kvar(?=\.png)/++$i/e'`

Comment: Ok, I have to check this one. Needs some time. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: @choroba Works! Great, thanks again for your answer.
I didn`t check the other suggestions, but thanks for it too.